# How can I run a command as another use + use user's environment/config variables from home folder in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I have a lot of configuration for Kwin (the window manager) in another user's home folder (`/home/B/.config` and other folders).

Is there a way to run Kwin from my session, but make Kwin consider the other user's configuration and environment as well?

I can't copy the files over to my account because they're scattered around B's home folder, and I don't want to risk overwriting stuff.

I tried using `sudo`, but it doesn't run the command as if it was the B's session, and uses my own config files to run the program instead of those in `/home/B/`.

Comment: try `sudo -H -u otherusername bash -c 'command'`

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that, but unfortunately the config files in B's home folder don't get picked up

Comment: may be try sourcing it before command `source .config && command`

Comment: I basically need everything setup as user B was logged in, Kwin looks for a lot of files in the home folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `-H` sudo parameter is not enough, maybe you also need something from shell resource files that `-i` would give you, so something like `sudo -i -uusername command`.

From sudo's man page:

```
       -i, --login Run the shell specified by the target user's password
                   database entry as a login shell.  This means that
                   login-specific resource files such as .profile or
                   .login will be read by the shell.  If a command is
                   specified, it is passed to the shell for execution
                   via the shell's -c option.  If no command is
                   specified, an interactive shell is executed.  sudo
                   attempts to change to that user's home directory
                   before running the shell.  The command is run with an
                   environment similar to the one a user would receive
                   at log in.  The Command environment section in the
                   sudoers(5) manual documents how the -i option affects
                   the environment in which a command is run when the
                   sudoers policy is in use.
```